# Pulling docker image in GKE

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I haven't found a solution in similar questions.
I'm trying to upload a docker image to Google Kubernetes Engine.
I've did it successfully before, but I can't seem to find my luck this time around.

I have Google SDK set up locally with kubectl and my Google Account, which is project owner and has all required permissions.
When I use

```
kubectl create deployment hello-app --image=gcr.io/{project-id}/hello-app:v1
```

I see the deployment on my GKE console, consistently crashing as it "cannot pull the image from the repository.ErrImagePull Cannot pull image '' from the registry".

It provides 4 recommendations, which I have by now triple checked:

- Check for spelling mistakes in the image names.
- Check for errors when pulling the images manually (all fine in Cloud Shell)
- Check the image pull secret settings
  So, based on this https://blog.container-solutions.com/using-google-container-registry-with-kubernetes, I manually added 'gcr-json-key' from a new service account with project view permissions as well as 'gcr-access-token' to kubectl default service account.
- Check the firewall for the cluster to make sure the cluster can connect to the ''. Afaik, this should not be an issue with a newly set up cluster.

The pods themselve provide the following error code:

```
Failed to pull image "gcr.io/{project id}/hello-app:v1": 
[rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: 
Get https://gcr.io/v2/{project id}/hello-app/manifests/v1: unknown: Unable to parse json key., 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: 
Get https://gcr.io/v2/{project id}/hello-app/manifests/v1: 
unauthorized: Not Authorized., rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: 
pull access denied for gcr.io/{project id}/hello-app, 
repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: 
Permission denied for "v1" from request "/v2/{project id}/hello-app/manifests/v1".]
```

My question now, what am I doing wrong or how can I find out why my pods can't pull my image?

---

Kubernetes default serviceaccount spec:

```
kubectl get serviceaccount -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "imagePullSecrets": [
        {
            "name": "gcr-json-key"
        },
        {
            "name": "gcr-access-token"
        }
    ],
    "kind": "ServiceAccount",
    "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": "2020-11-25T15:49:16Z",
        "name": "default",
        "namespace": "default",
        "resourceVersion": "6835",
        "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/default",
        "uid": "436bf59a-dc6e-49ec-aab6-0dac253e2ced"
    },
    "secrets": [
        {
            "name": "default-token-5v5fb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does take several steps and the blog post you referenced appears to have them correctly. So, I suspect your error is in one of the steps.

Couple of things:

- The error message says `Failed to pull image "gcr.io/{project id}/hello-app:v1"`. Did you edit the error message to remove your `{project id}`? If not, that's one problem.
- My next concern is the second line: `Unable to parse json key`. This suggests that you created the secret incorrectly:

1. Create the service account and generate a key
2. Create the Secret **exactly** as shown: `kubectl create secret docker-registry gcr-json-key...` (in the `default` namespace unless `--namespace=...` differs)
3. Update the Kubernetes spec with `ImagePullSecrets`

Because of the `ImagePullSecrets` requirement, I'm not aware of an alternative `kubectl run` equivalent but, you can try accessing your image using Docker from your host:

See: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#json-key

And then try `docker pull gcr.io/{project id}/hello-app:v1` ensuring that `{project id}` is replaced with the correct GCP Project ID.

This proves:

- The Service Account & Key are correct
- The Container Image is correct

That leaves, your creation of the Secret and your Kubernetes spec to test.

> **NOTE** The Service Account IAM permission of `Project Viewer` is overly broad for GCR access, see the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles)
>
> Use `StorageObject Viewer` (`roles/storage.objectViewer`) if the Service Account needs only to pull images.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate comment. 
- I did indeed edit the error and changed my project id for this post. 
- It could very well be the json key. In step two you mention to add the secret key exactly as in the post, does that include the path to the key file? Cause I used my local path, i.e.
`kubectl create secret docker-registyr gcr-json-key --docker-name=gcr.io --docker-username=_json_key --docker-password="$(cat C:/user/{path to local key}/key.json)" --docker-email=any@valid.email`
- About the Kubernetes spec, I attached the default kubectl serviceaccount specs.

Comment: Given that the local path nor the exactly shown version works, do I have to upload my key to a cloud storage and change the path in `kubectl create secret ...` to a cloud storage directory?

Comment: It appears you're running on Windows. The command `$(cat C:/user/{path to local key}` may be incorrect. Does `cat C:/user/{path to local key` display your key? Does `echo $(cat C:/user/{path to local key}` do the same thing? On Linux, this construct copies and pastes the value of the key file into the environment variable.

Comment: No, you may generate the secret from your local file system (see my previous comment). `kubectl` takes care of generating the secret for you on your cluster.

Comment: I've not used the mechanism of adding `imagePullSecrets` to the Kubernetes default service account but, it makes sense and should work. I generally reference the secret from within a Deployment spec. I'm going to try this approach as I have a cluster and a private registry on GHCR that I can test

Comment: Ok, `patch`ing the service account worked for me with my secret. I suspect your problem is in the creation of the secret

Comment: So `cat C:/...` displays my key, `echo $(cat path)` simply echo's `$(cat path)`. 
I just tried with `---docker-password="cat path"`, but still no luck. 
I also couldn't find this in the kubernetes documentation?
It might be worth mentioning that `kubectl get secrets gcr-json-key -o jsonpath='{.data}'`  outputs `{".dockerconfigjson": [key]}`. The key seems to be approx a private key's length, but it's not the key in my GCP service account json I want it to be...

Comment: To add to the whole story, I just followed https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#windows_2 and logged in Docker with the service account. I got 'login succeeded', but now I directly get a deployment error, `... connected party did not properly respond ...`